# How to prevent a numeric string Array from being rounded up/down in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm creating a Facebook game using HTML & Javascript, I'm currently working on rewarding people for inviting others to the game. To do this I run a check whenever a new player joins - I query Facebook's Graph API to get a list of IDs of people who have invited the new player.

My problem is this, this query returns an array of IDs, which is fine, but it seems as though the IDs are coming back as integers, and because Javascript have a limit on integer sizes in an array, some of these IDs are being rounded up or down by 1 number. This means that some of the IDs are incorrect.

I'm sending this array to my database using an Ajax Post, but the php file is failing because the rounded IDs don't exist in my database.

The ID column in my database is VARCHAR, so I think the php file will work if the data is sent in a string format instead of an int. And I know that Javascript has no problem storing the correct IDs in an array if it's storing them as a string instead of an int.

My question is, how do I get the response from the Graph API call to be stored as a string, rather than an int? Facebook's documents here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/apprequests/ state that when you read the apprequests for a user you receive a list of AppRequest nodes. This page (on AppRequest nodes) https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/app-request/ states that the `from` parameter is returned as a User object. And this page (on the User object) https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/ states that IDs are returned as a "numeric string". But the rounding up/down is still happening in Javascript.

This is the query to the Graph API:

```
function getRequests() {

FB.login(function(response) {
  if (response.authResponse) {
    console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');

//This is the call to Facebook...
     FB.api('me/apprequests?fields=to,from,id', function(response) {

     if (response.error) {
       console.log('Error - ' + response.error.message);
     }
     else {

    var requestid = [];

//Iterating through the response, and inserting all "from" IDs into the array...
    for(var i = 0; i < response.data.length; i++){
    requestid.push(response.data[i].from.id);
    }

    console.log(requestid);

//Sending the array to the database...
       $.ajax({
        url: 'php_scripts/sendinviterewards.php',
        data: {'requestid' : requestid},
        type: "POST",
        success: function(response){
            console.log(response);
                    }
       });
     }
    });
  } else {
    console.log('User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.');
  }
 }, {scope: 'email, user_birthday'});
}
```

Perhaps the IDs are being returned as numeric strings, but my use of Javascript is causing the larger ID numbers to be rounded. If this is the case, what would be the best way to solve this problem? Would I need to use a different language? Or is there some work around using Javascript? Thanks in advance!

Comment: "and because Javascript have a limit on integer sizes in an array "... Do you have ids bigger than `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER` (2^53-1) which is 9007199254740991..?

Comment: Hi @Redu , I had numbers larger than that, they weren't IDs from my database, they were ones assigned to players by Facebook so I had no control over them, but I just managed to get it resolved

Comment: Well ok then converting them to string seems to be one way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not completely sure what is causing this but can you try this :

```
for(var i = 0; i < response.data.length; i++){
    var id = new String(response.data[i].from.id);  
    requestid.push(id);
}
```